# If $p> \sqrt{|G|}$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ be a prime dividing the size $|G|$ of $G$ such that $p > \sqrt{|G|}$.
Prove that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p$.

I tried generalizing the proof of Cauchy's theorem (that there is a subgroup of order $p$, not necessarily normal), but didn't seem to work. Any help appreciated!

(Feel free to use group actions, but please avoid e.g. outsorcing to Sylow theorems, if possible.)

Comment: Has the theory of Sylow subgroups been covered yet in your studies? My guess is that if it hasn't, it will be the next topic. What about group actions? Anyway, answerers need to know a bit more about your background.

Comment: Ok, if $|G| = pm$, then $p$ does not divide $m$ since $p > \sqrt{|G|}$ and by Sylow the number of Sylow subgroups is $\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and divides $m$, hence is $1$. Again by Sylow, this number is the index of the normalizer of any Sylow subgroup $P$ of size $p$ (and $P$ exists by another theorem of Sylow), so this index is $1$ and hence $P$ is normal. Ok fine, thanks, but any idea for a proof which does not rely on so much theory?

Comment: For example, if $H\le G$, and $|H|=p$. The group $G$ acts on the set of cosets $G/H$? Observe that $|G/H|=m<p$, and the group $S_m$ has no elements of order $p$. Therefore the action homomorphism $G\to S_m$ has a non-trivial kernel such that  _______?

Comment: Yes yes, group actions are pretty fine, in fact via them is the only way I know how to prove Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen non-trivial kernel such that $H$ belongs to it. Since kernels of homomorphisms are normal subgroups, we are done. Correct?

Comment: That is the general idea, but I would phrase a few details differently. Because the order of $S_m$ is not divisible by $p$, the kernel must have order divisible by $p$. On the other hand the kernel is contained in $H$ (the kernel of this homomorphism is the core). Therefore the kernel must be exactly $H$, and hence $H\unlhd G$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$ (Cauchy guarantees its existence , $p | |G||$) and assume $H$ is *not* normal. Then there exists a $g \in G$ with $H^g:=g^{-1}Hg \neq H$, whence (using Lagrange and $p$ being prime) $H \cap H^g=1$. Observe that $g \notin H$ and this implies that the set $HH^g$ is a *proper* subset of $G$ (if $G=HH^g$, then $g=hg^{-1}kg$ $(h,k \in H)$, from which $g=kh \in H$ follows). But then $|G| \gt |HH^g|= \frac{|H||H^g|}{|H \cap H^g|}= p^2$. This yields $p \lt \sqrt{|G|}$, a contradiction. So $H$ must be normal.

Answer (score 5):

Promoting the comments to an answer as the OP worked it out to some extent. See Nicky Hekster's answer for an even lower tech argument.

---

Let $|G|=mp$, so $m<p$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$ (Cauchy's theorem promises the existence). Let $X=G/H$ be the set of left cosets of $H$. Then

- $G$ acts (transitively) on the set $X$ by left multiplication, this gives a group homomorphism $f:G\to \mathrm{Sym}(X)\simeq S_m$.
- The stabilizer of the coset $1H=H\in X$ is obviously $H$, so we can conclude that $\mathrm{Ker}(f)\le H$.
- On the other hand, because $m<p$, the group $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ has no elements of order $p$. Therefore elements of order $p$ must be mapped to the identity permutation (here it is crucial that $p$ is a prime), and we can deduce that $H\le \mathrm{Ker}(f)$.
- Therefore $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=H$. Consequently $H\unlhd G$ as the kernel of a homomorphism.

Comment: No problem Jirky

Comment: +1 from me anyway!